# Query entire DB for certain value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating a php application that is the front end for a database.

Database Server Type: MySQL version 5.5.32

Web Server Type: Apache/2.4.4

OpenSSL: 0.9.8y

PHP 5.4.16

When populating the DB any blank fields that would need to be addressed in the future were entered as "TBD". I would like to create a query that searches the entire DB for fields that are equal to "TBD". If possible I would like the output of the query to have the following information:

```
Table Name: 
Field Name:
Primary Key:
```

The PKs for all of my tables are named with the following convention: table name + ID. For example if a table is named "client" it's primary key field is called "clientID". I have set up a version of this report using arrays of the table names and fields name to generate multiple sql queries but I have to believe that there is a SQL wiz out there who can get this done in if not 1, just a query per table? This would be extremely beneficial because it would not require me to update the report, every time I make a change to the DB. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you put a value for blank fields and not just keep them as `null`?

Comment: It allows us to differentiate between fields that need to be entered, and fields that are left blank purposely.

Comment: a blank field containing `''` and a `null` field are also not the same :)

Comment: Fair point, it was a specific request of the system owner to have TBD values so sometimes you have to work with those requirements even if they are not ideal.

Comment: @JohnCarroll Tell the system owner they're idiots.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a script called anywhereindb

Download it here: 
https://code.google.com/p/anywhereindb/

You simply have to upload a php file to your server, add the DB credentials and it'll search for a string throughout the DB. It has been very helpful.

Remember to delete the file after using it if is publicly accesible.

Answer (score -1):

Try constructing your queries like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl,
     tbl1,
     tbl2...tblx
WHERE tabl.condition OR ...
```